# QSqlTableModel filter no results

Tags: c++, mysql, qt, qsqltablemodel

I'm trying to access mysql a database in qt c++.

I have different tables and want to output them on a `QTableView`.

I use the `QSqlTableModel`, which works great, but as soon as I want to filter the results I run into problems..

Here is the main part of my source code:

```
mModelContacts->setTable("contacts");
mModelContacts->select();
mUi->tableContacts->setModel(mModelContacts);

void MainWindow::on_submitContactsButton_clicked()
{

switch(mUi->comboBoxContacts->currentIndex())
{
    case 0:
        mModelContacts->setFilter("contacts_id = "+mUi->searchContactsLine->text());
        break;
    case 1:
        mModelContacts->setFilter("contacts_firstName LIKE "+'%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%');
        break;
    case 2:
        mModelContacts->setFilter("contacts_lastName LIKE "+'%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%');
        break;
    case 3:
        mModelContacts->setFilter("contacts_city LIKE "+'%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%');
        break;
    case 4:
        mModelContacts->setFilter("contacts_phoneNumber LIKE "+'%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%');
        break;
}

mModelContacts->select();
mUi->tableContacts->setModel(mModelContacts);
```

}

The ID Filter (case 0) works fine. But everything else (firstname, lastname etc.) does not. I just get an empty table showed. So I can see the column names (therefore I think that my sql syntax is correct) but there is no entry, no matter what I type in.

Is there a mistake in my source code? Or how can I get this to work?

Comment: Try to inspect your query string with qDebug(), for example qDebug() << QString("contacts_firstName LIKE "+'%'+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+'%'); and post your result

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with you adding the `char*` C-style string (`"contacts_firstName LIKE "`) to the the `char` (`'%'`), this will lead to the following:

1. the `char`(`'%'`) will be casted  to an integer (its representation in ASCII), in order to perform the addition, have a look at [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Numeric_promotions).
2. the integer resulted from the cast (`37`) will be added to the `char*` C-style string, this will get you into memory that you haven't initialized (maybe other C-style strings that you have in your read-only data section).
3. after that `QString` adds data from the evil pointer resulting above (until it finds a `'\0'` character) to the string that is in your line edit, resulting in a `QString` that you are clearly not aiming for. . .

in summary you should replace your `setFilter` calls with something like this:

```
mModelContacts->setFilter(QString("contacts_firstName LIKE '%")+mUi->searchContactsLine->text()+QString("%'"));
```

Comment: You solved it! Thanks a lot :) You made my day!
Seems I still have to learn a lot..